# Why does str.lstrip strip an extra character?

Tags: python, string

```
>>> path = "/Volumes/Users"
>>> path.lstrip('/Volume')
's/Users'
>>> path.lstrip('/Volumes')
'Users'
>>>
```

I expected the output of `path.lstrip('/Volumes')` to be `'/Users'`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) is character-based, it removes all characters from the left end that are in that string.

To verify this, try this:

```
"/Volumes/Users".lstrip("semuloV/")  # also returns "Users"
```

Since `/` is part of the string, it is removed.

You need to use slicing instead:

```
if s.startswith("/Volumes"):
    s = s[8:]
```

Or, on Python 3.9+ you can use [`removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix):

```
s = s.removeprefix("/Volumes")
```

Comment: That is the "one obvious way to do it".

Comment: To more efficiently remove the prefix, use split, with maxsplits=1
`path = "/Volumes/Users"
drive = "/Volumes"
if path.startswith(drive):
    path = path.split(drive, 1)[1]`

Answer (score 17):

Strip is character-based. If you are trying to do path manipulation you should have a look at [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)

```
>>> os.path.split("/Volumes/Users")
('/Volumes', 'Users')
```

Comment: These days, use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) instead: `from pathlib import Path` and then `Path("/Volumes/Users").name` or `Path("/Volumes/Users").parts[-1]`

Answer (score 16):

The argument passed to `lstrip` is taken as a set of characters!

```
>>> '   spacious   '.lstrip()
'spacious   '
>>> 'www.example.com'.lstrip('cmowz.')
'example.com'
```

See also the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

You might want to use str.replace()

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])
# e.g.
'/Volumes/Home'.replace('/Volumes', '' ,1)
```

Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

For paths, you may want to use `os.path.split()`. It returns a list of the paths elements.

```
>>> os.path.split('/home/user')
('/home', '/user')
```

To your problem:

```
>>> path = "/vol/volume"
>>> path.lstrip('/vol')
'ume'
```

The example above shows, how `lstrip()` works. It removes '/vol' starting form left. Then, is starts again...
So, in your example, it fully removed '/Volumes' and started removing '/'. It only removed the '/' as there was no 'V' following this slash.

HTH

Comment: `'/home/user/Volumes/important_path'.replace('/Volumes', '', 1)` -->
`'/home/user/important_path'`

Comment: Or `'/home/user/Volumes_for_my_mp3s/jazz'.replace('/Volumes', '', 1)` --> `'/home/user_for_my_mp3s/jazz'`. See what you're missing yet? :)

Comment: yes. I know... str.replace was just an example for this specific example from Vijayendra Bapte.

Comment: If it doesn't apply to the general case, then say so: maybe *his* example was just *one* of the hundred cases he needs to run this on.

Comment: @Mark: I wrote: 'Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.'

Answer (score 1):

lstrip doc says:

```
Return a copy of the string S with leading whitespace removed.
If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping
```

So you are removing every character that is contained in the given string, including both 's' and '/' characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a primitive version of lstrip (that I wrote) that might help clear things up for you:

```
def lstrip(s, chars):
    for i in range len(s):
        char = s[i]
        if not char in chars:
            return s[i:]
        else:
            return lstrip(s[i:], chars)
```

Thus, you can see that every occurrence of a character in chars is is removed until a character that is not in chars is encountered. Once that happens, the deletion stops and the rest of the string is simply returned