# Are there limits to using string.lstrip() in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this a bug in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148974/is-this-a-bug-in-python-2-7)

The .lstrip() function doesn't quite work as I expected on some strings (especially ones with underscores). e.g.,

```
In [1]:  a='abcd_efg_hijk_lmno_pqrs_tuvw_xyz'   
In [2]: a.lstrip('abcd_efg')   
Out[2]: 'hijk_lmno_pqrs_tuvw_xyz'
```

Here, the '_' between 'g' and 'h' is missing. Any idea as to why this happens?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.lstrip()` doesn't do what you think it does. It removes *any of the provided characters* from the left end of the string. The second underscore is as much an underscore as the first, so it got removed too.

```
"aaaaaaaabbbbbbbc".lstrip("ab")  # "c"
```

Comment: i see... so how would one strip string1 exactly from the left of string2? if it helps, i know for sure that string2 is of the form string1+string3.

Comment: For a quick and dirty way `"my_string"[len("my"):]`

Answer (score 7):

What you want:

```
b = 'abcd_efg'
if a.startswith(b):
    a = a[len(b):]
```

As the [`str.lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) documentation says,

> The chars argument is not a prefix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:
>
> ```
> >>> 'www.example.com'.lstrip('cmowz.')
> 'example.com'
> ```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want:

```
>>> a = "foobar"
>>> sub = "foo"
>>> b = a[len(sub):]
>>> b
'bar'
```