# Find the unmatched string within another string in python

Tags: python, string, difference

Suppose i have two strings in python:

```
    str1 = 'WeDrank$varCupCoffeeToday'
    str2 = 'WeDrank2CupCoffeeToday'
```

We can clearly see that there the difference between them are $var and 2. How do we obtain 2 as an output  assuming $var may be in any position i.e

```
    str1 = 'WeDrank2CupCoffee$var'
    str2 = 'WeDrank2CupCoffeeToday'
```

So here the output should be Today. Anticipating the best suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $var will be present in any case?

Comment: Is it always going to be the string `"$var"`?

Comment: yes $var is a symbol to represent the portion of string inside another string. For eg in first set $var represent 2 and in second it represent Today.

Comment: yes it is always going to be $var everytime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split on the token `'$var'`, then replace the two parts from the left and right sides respectively with an empty string, and you will get the value of the token.

```
>>> str1 = 'WeDrank$varCupCoffeeToday'
>>> str2 = 'WeDrank2CupCoffeeToday'
>>> parts = str1.split('$var')
>>> str2.replace(parts[0],'').replace(parts[1],'')
'2'
>>> str1 = 'WeDrank2CupCoffee$var'
>>> str2 = 'WeDrank2CupCoffeeToday'
>>> parts = str1.split('$var')
>>> str2.replace(parts[0],'').replace(parts[1],'')
'Today'
```

Comment: unfortunately it won't for urls

Comment: Finally i found the good solution that will work for simple strings and url is replace lstrip with replace function as:str2.replace(parts[0],'').replace(parts[1],'')

Comment: what if we have str1 = 'WeDrank$var1CupCoffeeTodayWith$var2Persons' and str2 ='WeDrank2CupCoffeeTodayWith6Persons' situation? I mean for a dynamic situation where there might be any number of $var ?

Comment: @user2789099 You failed to mention that in your original question... also, I don't see how this wouldn't work for a URL.

Comment: Yes, I had not mentioned, even though i am asking. Yes, I tried with url it didn't worked.

Comment: @user2789099 can you post the input you used which didn't work? Maybe I can explain that.

Comment: str1 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/setLanguage/$var/' and str2 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/setLanguage/en/' are the two inputs for which it seem to be working but not working..

Comment: @user2789099 Wow, thanks for pointing that out! Turns out I was wrong about [what `lstrip` and `rstrip` do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4840805/691859).

Comment: you are welcome.. Did you find the reason that why it didn't worked?

Comment: @user2789099 Read the link I provided in my comment. As far as using multiple variables goes, you could use the `re` module to help with that, but I suggest you open a new question for that.